# Stripe Class 'Stripe\Charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to implement a Stripe payment form but I get a fatal error Class 'Stripe\Charge. The class is there (see my folder tree), I tried :

```
$charge =  \Stripe\Charge::create(array(

$charge =  \Charge::create(array(
```

but both no working.
my php code:

```
require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("my_key"); //Replace with your Secret Key

$charge =  \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1500,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    "description" => "Charge for Facebook Login code."
));
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an older (1.x) version of the Stripe PHP library. In that version, all the classes were named `Stripe_Class`.

In version [2.0.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2015-02-14), the syntax was changed to use a namespace, and now all the classes are named `\Stripe\Class`.

If it's possible, I recommend you upgrade to the latest version (3.13.0). You can find it here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases. All the examples in Stripe's documentation and API reference use the newer syntax.

Answer (score 3):

**you can use**

```
use \Stripe\Stripe;
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("my_key");
 public function chargeCard($token)
 {
    try
    {
        $charge=\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 200,//Amount in cent.(100 cent equal to $1.00).it is smallest currency unit
            "currency" => "usd",//united state dollar .but we can use different countries currency code
            "source" => $token, // obtained createtoken function
            "description" => "Charge for testing"//desc of payment purpose,Automatic receipt emails will include the description of the charge(s)
          )
          );
      }
      catch(\Stripe\Card $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer-email',
      'source'  => 'stripe_token'
  ));

  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $order_amount, // amount in cents
    "customer"=>$customer->id,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com"
  ));
```